# Модификация Jira с помощью api/rest api

Tags: c#, jira

Здравствуйте. Нужно поизучать Jira и возможности работы с ней из вне. Конкретно нужно для начала хотя бы добиться смены статуса задачи сторонним приложением. Не подскажите где взять открытые api для Jira. Или может у кого то есть такие наработки?

Comment: [это?](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis)

Comment: @tym32167 не совсем. Нужно конкретно версии 5.2.11. нашёл в нугете Atlassian.SDK. Для работы с Jira из c# . Только не пойму оно это или нет. Но там нет версии 5.2.11

Comment: [Оно?](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/5.2.11/)

Comment: [Вот](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home) sdk, что вы нашли. Смотрите, изучайте. Там можно любую версию самому сбрать, при необходимости.

Comment: @tym32167 второе вроде оно. Но там не киких надстроек для c#. А вот то что скинули последнее. Да тот самый sdk. А можно поподробнее как собирать конкретную версию? просто в нугете я видел либо 5.2.0, либо 5.3.0. Не подскажите как сделать или где скачать для версии 5.2.11?

Comment: Я поясню, что я не работаю с jira через api, я просто умею гуглить лучше вас. По поводу конкретной версии - при установке пакета из нугета вы можете указать весию, что хотите установить https://www.nuget.org/packages/Atlassian.SDK.

Comment: Чтобы не было путаницы, версия нугет пакета != версия API для джиры

Comment: @tym32167 а тогда как узнать, или как провести эквивалент от версии нугет пакета до версии джиры? Или можно просто скачать последнюю версию нугет пакета Atlassian.sdk? И как в таком случае работать именно под версию api jira 5.2.11?

Comment: А это вопрос уже скорее к разработчику sdk